# wrap_content não esta funcionando

Tags: android, android-xml

Estou com um erro com o wrap_content no android no meu ImageButton eu set a imagem diretamente de um URL

**EXEMPLO:**

```
ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
Picasso.with(getContext()).load("https://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png").fit().into(img);
```

e o XML desta ImageButton é o seguinte

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd" />
```

**Exibição de imagem que recebo**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Retire `android:scaleType="fitEnd"` ou use `android:scaleType="center"`

Comment: @ramaral não funcionou, tirei o `android:scaleType="fitEnd"` e também tentei colocando o `android:scaleType="center"`

Comment: Retire o scaleType e adicione `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: O adjustViewBounds (em API's menores que a 17) não "estica" a imagem para ocupar toda a imageView, caso a imagem seja menor. Para imagens maiores que a ImageView ela "encolhe" corretamente. Tem que tratar isso se for o caso se for usar esse atributo.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira julgo que nesta situação não tem problema, já que está a ser usado `wrap_content`

Comment: @ramaral, dê uma olhada: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/correct-imageview-adjustviewbounds-with-adjustable-imageview/en

Comment: @MárcioOliveira É, eu sei. O problema é que não sei se o AP quer que a imagem aumente ou fique com o tamanho que tem. Mas como ele diz que `fitCenter` não resolveu deve ser porque ele quer que aumente e nesse caso `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` só funciona para API17+.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira estou usando API 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `wrap_content` em ImageViews só funciona se a imagem já for de tamanho conhecido, visto que o layout é inflado assim que a Activity começa. E no seu caso a sua imagem ainda será carregada da web.

Minha sugestão, já que você está usando o Picasso, é carregar a imagem como um Bitmap para um `Target` e usar o método de callback `onBitmapLoaded()` do mesmo para determinar que a imagem está pronta, então você ainda nesse método pode acessar as propriedades de width e height da imagem e redimensionar a ImageView de acordo com o `SetLayoutParams()`.

Algo assim:

```
        Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                    // OBS: Crie um LayoutParams de acordo com o ViewGroup pai da ImageView. 
                    // No meu exemplo, estou supondo que a ImageView está dentro de um 
                    // FrameLayout.
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
        };

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .into(target);
```

Comment: Tentei com seu codigo e nele o programa crasha na linha do Picasso

Comment: Qual linha e qual erro?

Comment: Eu fiz ontem, para um projeto meu, algo parecido e funcionou, só que usando o Glide, em vez do Picasso.

Comment: estou pegando o Url da imagem no bd, com o codigo que postei na pergunta o ImageButton recebia a imagem porem não aumentava, e com o seu ele simplesmente crasha na parte que chama o target dentro do Picasso

Comment: Estranho. Peguei esse código dos tutoriais do próprio Picasso. Só editei a parte do OnBitmapLoaded(). Seria legal postar o erro exato, pois não costumo usar o Picasso. Como disse, eu uso mais o Glide.

Comment: ah sim, desculpe de tantas alterações não estou mais com o erro, acho que me convem utilizar o `resize()` do Picasso

Comment: Sou novato no SOpt, e também em android